# How to call a constructor of a object that is also aWeakReference

Tags: java, weak-references

So I have this:

```
    private WeakReference<ViewThread> mThread;
```

And I want to call the constructor of `ViewThread`, like `new ViewThread(this)`  and assign the resulting instance to `mThread`;

But whatever I try, it gives me compilation errors, because it cannot reconcile the type  `ViewThread` with the type `WeakReference`  Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need,

```
mThread = new WeakReference<ViewThread>(new ViewThread(this));
```

Comment: Oh, I see. So a constructed object goes in the parens. Thank you. This problem  came from me not knowing the notation in the API.

Comment: There's no 'notation'. A WeakReference is not some sort of language trick, it's just a class. If you want to make one, you have to make it with new, just as you'd make a new one of anything else.

Comment: The "notation" part came from not knowing what went in the parentheses in the inspector. On the API it said "`WeakReference (T r)`". I didn't know what the "T r" meant.